# How to run forked processes in some order?

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing, ipc

Given the scenario, I am asked to paint the boxes which have various color tags which indicate the color that the boxes will be painted with and those boxes arrive at a painting unit which has a box capacity of 2, which means it can only paint 2 boxes concurrently. The unit can not paint different colors at the same time. It has to wait for a color of boxes to finish before changing the color and paint other boxes.

Processes and threads will be used in the process. The problem is, I am asked to paint the boxes in a FIFO manner. Consider the example below:

```
Box #1    Box #2    Box #3    Box #4    Box #5
  R         B         G         R         B
```

I have to paint in the given order:

```
Box #1, Box #4, Box #2, Box #5, Box #3
  R        R       B       B        G
```

I can arrange the color sequence which the unit will use to paint boxes(RBG in this case) by the help of a pointer, but I cannot guarantee that the boxes will be painted in the given order, i.e. the order might be `4 1 5 2 3` instead of `1 4 2 5 3`, thus I will violate the FIFO rule since there will be #ofBoxes processes will be running(not concurrently, in total) and the order is not determined. The only method I could think of was (somehow) considering the order of the forked processes (each box) and somehow prioritize the painting operation but I don't think this is even a solution. This could be solved easily by a sequential approach (sorting then painting), but considering IPC and concurrent processes, sorting will not help at all, at least won't guarantee any ordering.

I am kind of stuck here and I am only asking a hint to solve the problem, not the exact solution. Please be as abstract as you can. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Excuse me for not mentioning some necessary details.
I am forced to model each box as a separate process and not to use signals for synchronization.

Comment: Have you considered making the painting device(s) a process and let the boxes be objects passed to the painting device(s) by a scheduling process? Instead of associating a process/thread with each box.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I forgot to mention some details. Please refer to question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always start the processes one-by-one, and `wait` for the new process to finish before you start the next one.

Or you can use pipe to chain all processes together, making the `stdout` of the first process connect to `stdout` of the second, and so on. Then in the child process you don't continue until you get some input from the previous process to continue.

Or use something like [named semaphores](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_open.html) to signal each other.

Comment: I forgot to mention some details. Can you please see the question's edit part? Thanks for your attention anyway.

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli The first solution in my answer doesn't involve any signaling between the processes.

Comment: I see the way to the solution now. Thanks for your answer:)

Comment: There is one more problem as I have seen. I have to keep track of their original index of the boxes that are going to be painted. I have a `char` array in the shared memory, and with only that its sort of not possible to paint in order which they arrived *and* keep track of their original index. If i sort them, I can start processes one by one and get the FIFO ordering but I will loose the index which I also need. If I don't sort them, I cannot see a way to accomplish what is desired (FIFO will be violated). Can you see a way out from this?